# My CSS suddenly doesn't load anymore

Tags: css, errors, wp-enqueue-style

I've did some small changes on my CSS, nothing crazy, uploaded them to my website. Cleared my cache and suddenly, the website doesn't show my custom styles.

Website: http://experienceantwerp.be/

My styles are included in the enqueue.php file, but it always worked.

```
if (!function_exists('understrap_scripts')) {
    /**
     * Load theme's JavaScript and CSS sources.
     */
    function understrap_scripts()
    {
        // Get the theme data.
        $the_theme = wp_get_theme();
        $theme_version = $the_theme->get('Version');

        wp_enqueue_style('slider-slider-styles', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('lity-style', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lity/2.4.1/lity.min.css');
        $css_version = $theme_version . '.' . filemtime(get_template_directory() . '/css/theme.min.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('understrap-styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/theme.min.css', array(), $css_version);

        }
    }
} // endif function_exists( 'understrap_scripts' ).

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'understrap_scripts', 10);
```

If I check my source code in the browser, it seems that the slider-slider-styles and lity-style are loaded, but not my styles "understrap-styles".

The file is available on the server because I can directly open the file in my browser.

Comment: What does `var_dump( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() )` output? Maybe a plugin/code is changing the value? Try also removing the version or set `$css_version` to `null` just for testing.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove an additional } on line 18. Try the following

```
<?php

if (!function_exists('understrap_scripts')) {
    /**
     * Load theme's JavaScript and CSS sources.
     */
    function understrap_scripts()
    {
        // Get the theme data.
        $the_theme = wp_get_theme();
        $theme_version = $the_theme->get('Version');

        wp_enqueue_style('slider-slider-styles', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('lity-style', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lity/2.4.1/lity.min.css');
        $css_version = $theme_version . '.' . filemtime(get_template_directory() . '/css/theme.min.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('understrap-styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/theme.min.css', array(), $css_version);
    }
} // endif function_exists( 'understrap_scripts' ).

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'understrap_scripts', 10);
```

Comment: Sorry the } was a typo while copying it into Stackexchange. I don't have that extra } in my actual code.

I seems that my css is loading when I add the absolute path: wp_enqueue_style('understrap-styles', 'https://experienceantwerp.be/wp-content/themes/framework_wp/css/theme.min.css'); Strange...